# Making \cites behave like \cite?

Tags: biblatex

My faculty style guidelines expect me to cite without page numbers. But while writing I'd like to work with page numbers to make checking references easier. So I would like to be able to use page numbers, but hide them in the final pdf.

My current idea is to use a custom cite command:
`\citepage[116]{schonherr2015}`

During work I can show the page:`\newcommand{\citepage}[2][]{\cite[#1]{#2}}`

And for the final version I would use: `\newcommand{\citepage}[2][]{\cite{#2}}`

This approach works for single references, but I don't know what to do when citing multiple references with page numbers at once (e.g `\cites[116]{schonherr2015}[15]{Smith2002}`). Is it possible to create a custom command similar to what I did for \cite above? Or do you have suggestions for a different/better workflow?

Comment: Hi, welcome. First, a question. Would you like to just disregard the postnote for *all* your citations? Or just in some cases? Second, even though your question seems reasonably clear, you might stand a better chance of getting an answer if you provide a MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/105447 (you can edit your question for that).

Comment: Hi, yes i would like to disregard the postnote for all my citations. While as I was preparing a MWE @moewe already answered. Anyways, I will take your advice into account in the future. Thank you both for your help!

Comment: Then moewe's answer is the way to go indeed.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your style guidelines are making a huge mistake when they want you to cite without page references. Page references are extremely useful.

It is not always possible to persuade those in charge to come to their senses, so here is a solution to suppress all postnotes in citations. It should work for most citation styles.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}

\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocites[12]{nussbaum}[13]{worman}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [2] ipsum [1, 3]]